# How to run Django after Ubuntu 14.04 install

Tags: python, django, installation, pip

I am brand new to programming, but hopefully someone can help and this makes sense.

When I run python from the terminal in Ubuntu it runs it from the following path.

```
/homeX/your_username/python27/bin/python
```

I used pip to install django which worked successfully, but it installed it to this path.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django
```

Therefore, when I run python in the terminal it can't find the django framework.  Also, Ubuntu won't allow me to copy anything into the `homeX/` directory so I can't manually add django either.

Comment: You really should be using [virtualenv](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/).

Comment: If you haven't already, go here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/  Read the install notes and then do the tutorial.  Django docs are great for beginner and advanced alike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install django` It will install into global and in any directory `django-admin.py startproject` to create your Django project.

So after installing django you can import django from the python shell

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>>
```

So as `@Filly` suggested use `virtualenv` is best for working with django and installing packages

```
pip install virtualenv==1.11.6
```

after installing try below commands

```
virtualenv source/bin/activate
```

And after you are in virtual environment. Here you can install any packages Django or whatever it ll lie in environment only.

Answer (score 1):

Django can work without virtual env in ubuntu

install django

```
sudo pip install django==1.7 
or 
Sudo pip install django==1.8
```

The path of django installation module repo

```
python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django;
print(django.__path__)"
```

Now goto terminal

```
$ python


>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
```

Now start a django project

1. sudo django-admin startproject project_name
2. cd project_name
3. python manage.py runserver or python manage.py runserver 8008
4. Goto browser --> localhost:8000 (8000 is default port)